# Meteor transition effects for auto-updating content

Tags: meteor

Looking at [the meteor leaderboard example](http://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard), I understand how content in the view templates  is bound to functions in the javascript application file.  For example, consider this snippet from the view file which defines the "selected" class to determine which name is highlighted yellow:

```
<template name="player">
  <div class="player {{selected}}">
    <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
    <span class="score">{{score}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

The value of `{{selected}}` is defined and kept up to date in this function from leaderboard.js:

```
Template.player.selected = function () {
    return Session.equals("selected_player", this._id) ? "selected" : '';
};
```

My question is: How would you add transition effects to this auto updating process?  For example, say we wanted the yellow highlighting to fade to white on the existing name, and then fade into yellow on the new name, whenever a new name was clicked.  How could we accomplish that in meteor?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be using CSS transitions. Just ensure that the element is preserved (so it isn't *replaced* on re-draw, just patched):

```
 Template.player.preserve(['.player']);
```

Then go nuts with the CSS transitions:

```
 .player {
   background-color: white;
   transition: background-color 500ms linear 0;
   -moz-transition: background-color 500ms linear 0;
   // etc
 }

 .player.selected {
   background-color: yellow;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Granted this could work for the example I gave, I was hoping for a more general solution.  That is, imagine the kind of complex transitions you might use in d3 with spiraling movements and vanishing to a point, etc.  I'd like to be able to integrate such things into a meteor app.

Comment: You can do arbitrarily complex animations with CSS, too.

Comment: what about reordering the list? I'd like it to not jump incomprehensibly.

Comment: This no longer works (in Meteor 1.0). You will get the all-encompassing: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function